# Creating simple left right gradient with top down alpha swift UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient, cagradientlayer

Would like to create simple custom UIView that fades from red to blue horizontally and then both colors have alphas that fade downwards to zero (so the top of the view is red to blue and the bottom is faded away to clear).

Have tried several simple and complicated routes but cannot get it right.

Sample Case, nesting UIViews (tried to create sub view that has gradient and layer alpha to main view)

```
class AlphaGradientView299: UIView {

// Main view with vertical alpha gradient
private let mainView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

// Nested view with left-to-right color gradient
private let nestedView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupSubviews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupSubviews()
}

private func setupSubviews() {
    addSubview(mainView)
    mainView.addSubview(nestedView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        
        nestedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor),
        nestedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor),
        nestedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.trailingAnchor),
        nestedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor),
        
       
        ])
    // Set up main view with vertical alpha gradient
    mainView.backgroundColor = .white
    let alphaLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    alphaLayer.frame = mainView.bounds
    alphaLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor,              UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor]
    alphaLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    alphaLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    mainView.layer.addSublayer(alphaLayer)
}
}

let testView: AlphaGradientView299 = {
    let v = AlphaGradientView299()
    return v
}()
self.view.addSubview(testView)
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

The above fails to even load a view.

Here's a different attempt using only CAGradientLayers:

```
class CustomGradientView100: UIView {

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}

var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupGradientLayer()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupGradientLayer()
}

private func setupGradientLayer() {
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    
    let alphaGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    alphaGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    alphaGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    alphaGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    alphaGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    alphaGradientLayer.frame = gradientLayer.bounds
    gradientLayer.insertSublayer(alphaGradientLayer, at: 0)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(alphaGradientLayer, at: 0)
    
}
}
```

Used black to see what was going on better but the above only creates a left right gradient, no top down fade.

Please help, am losing my mind

Edit (Lazarevzubov's View recreated as custom UIView Class):

```
class lazaView: UIView {

private var fadeLayer: CAGradientLayer!
  private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
  private var gradientView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupGradient()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupGradient()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    setupGradient()
}

private func setupGradient() {
    
    gradientView = UIView()
        gradientView.backgroundColor = .red
        gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(gradientView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
          gradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
          gradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
          gradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
          gradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])

        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]

        gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        fadeLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        fadeLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        fadeLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        fadeLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        fadeLayer.locations = [0, 1]

        gradientView.layer.addSublayer(fadeLayer)
    
    gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
        fadeLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is an edited answer, because at first, I missed the part with fading out.)

Here's an example of a `UIView` with a red-blue horizontal gradient:

```swift
final class GradientView: UIView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setupGradient()
  }

  private func setupGradient() {
    backgroundColor = .clear

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
  }

}
```

To make this view fade away, we can add a mask layer to it, like this:

```swift
final class GradientView: UIView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setup()
  }

  private func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .clear

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    // Here:

    let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    maskLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    maskLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    maskLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    maskLayer.frame = bounds

    layer.mask = maskLayer
  }

}
```

Here's a sample usage in a `UIViewController` (which has a green background as a proof of the view's transparency):

```swift
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .green

    let gradientView = GradientView()
    gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(gradientView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      gradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      gradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      gradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      gradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
  }

}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: The bottom part of `gradientView` isn't actually transparent though. It's just white because you used white in `fadeLayer.colors`.

Comment: lazarevzubov your image is exactly what I need + @Sweeper's comment but need it configured as a UIView class instead of UIViewController so I can give it a custom height and width of 50 for example and have a gradient square somewhere on the screen. The lower half I want an alpha because want to move things under that square and want those things to be visible under the square through the lower faded portion. I tried to rewrite your code as a custom UIView class above. Please see the end of my question and let me know what you think, unfortunately my rewrite fails to add lower fade,only colors

Comment: @ArtisticEndeavor I'm sorry, I totally missed the part with fading out. I updated the answer, it now uses a fading `UIView` with a gradient.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thank you, immensely. I would shake your hand if I could. This solution is brilliant.

Comment: it is a wrong answer - `layoutSubviews` may be called multiple times and you add gradient layer multiple times

Comment: It's not a "wrong" answer, the solution works. If you found a bug in it, feel free to update the answer and improve it.